# Search for a IF-ANY solution that works with <XSL:for-each>

Tags: xslt

I am searching for a solution for the following problem:

Currently i have this code:

```
<div class="box">
              <div class="header">
                <h2>Item</h2>
              </div>
   </div>
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)/* [name() = $documentTypeAlias and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '0']">
<xsl:if test="string(experuserid)=$currentPage/experuserid">


  <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="subtitel"/>
  <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" class="readmore">
 Lees meer         
    </a>
    </div>

  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This code produces a result for-each time my source(experuserid) equals my currentpage/experuserid.

The problem is when the test comes back negative and there are no experuserid's that match with the currentpage. I want to make it so that when this occures, my layout won't also show. Thus i need something like this:

```
<xsl:if-any test="string(experuserid)=$currentPage/experuserid">
    <div class="box">
                  <div class="header">
                    <h2>Item</h2>
                  </div>
       </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)/* [name() = $documentTypeAlias and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '0']">
    <xsl:if test="string(experuserid)=$currentPage/experuserid">


      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="subtitel"/>
      <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" class="readmore">
     Lees meer         
        </a>
        </div>

      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if-any>
```

Does this kind of solution exist? p.s. i am an XSLT-Rookie. I read something about using an if test with a * like so:

```
<xsl:if test="*string(experuserid)=$currentPage/experuserid">
```

But this does not work, any help?

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to count the number of matches and only do it if there are some ... something like this ...

```
<xsl:if test="count( child::Page[experuserid = string(experuserid)] ) > 0">
 <div ... blah ... />
</xsl:if>
```

not entirely sure what the "string(experuserid)" is doing (apart from obviously converting a textual number contained in the child node called experuserid of the current node into string, which it is already), you present it as working in your example so I'm re-using it ... but I have no context to determine it's validity.

Comment: Also, `test="count(expr) > 0"` is equivalent to `test="expr"`, when `expr` is selecting nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the filtering up front rather than using an `<xsl:if>` within the for-each, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="interestingNodes"
    select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)/*
       [name() = $documentTypeAlias and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '0']
       [experuserid=$currentPage/experuserid]"/>
```

This will store in the variable only the nodes that you are actually interested in processing (i.e. those with the right `experuserid`), which may of course be none of them.  Now you can simply say

```
<xsl:if test="$interestingNodes"><!-- true if $interestingNodes is non-empty -->
  <div class="box">
    ...
  </div>
  <xsl:for-each select="$interestingNodes">
    <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

P.S. note that the `string()` in your original test of `string(experuserid)=$currentPage/experuserid` is probably redundant.  If the node has exactly one `experuserid` child element then it makes no difference to the behaviour.  If the node has *more than one* `experuserid` then using `string()` will mean you check only the *first* `experuserid` child in document order, whereas without the `string()` it'll be true if any of them match.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select=
"umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)/* 
       [name() = $documentTypeAlias and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '0']
       [string(experuserid)=$currentPage/experuserid]
">

  <!-- Your other code here -->

</xsl:for-each>
```